How to change the temporary directory (tmp) for a Rails app to a custom path?
I'm trying to change the tmp directory used by my Rails application to a custom directory, but so far, nothing I've tried has worked.
I’ve followed several suggestions, such as setting the TMPDIR environment variable in various locations (e.g., shell, .bashrc, and service files). However, Rails still defaults to /tmp.
I came across this Stack Overflow question from 11 years ago, which states that it might not be possible to change the tmp directory, but this information is quite old.
Has anything changed in Rails since then? Is there now a Rails-specific configuration or another way to ensure the app consistently uses a custom tmp directory?
Any updated insights or working examples would be greatly appreciated.

Not much, as always, convention over configuration. Whats the need ?

Rails uses Dir.tmpdir in most places which gets the directory from the underlying operating system. And yes you can actually change it by setting the TMPDIR, TMP or TEMP  environmental variable. Try $ TMPDIR=./my_custom_temp_folder ruby -r "tempfile" -e "puts Dir.tmpdir" - as long as the folder exists and is writeable it should echo back TMPDIR.
